# What does the "combination" part of the Skilled feat mean?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, skills, proficiency

The [Skilled](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/skilled) feat says (*Player's Handbook*, p. 170; emphasis mine):

> You gain proficiency in any **combination of three skills or tools** of your choice.

Does it mean I have to choose either three skills or three tools? Or can I, for example, choose two skills and one tool?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE.  The [tour] and the [help] are nice introductions to the site.  Have fun and happy gaming.  :)  Details on [ask] and [answer] can be useful for future questions that you may have.  ]

Answer (score 22):

The latter. Sometimes, reading using plain English is where the answer is hidden.

> [You gain proficiency in any combination of three skills or tools of your choice](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/skilled).
>   (PHB, Ch 6)

The possible combinations are;
3 skills, no tools
2 skills, 1 tool
1 skill, 2 tools
no skills, 3 tools

You can choose *any* combination that you prefer.